# how to emit data from child to parent's parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Let's call this `my-input.vue` component

```
<input :value="value" v-on:input="input($event.target.value)" @focus="focus">

    export default {
        props: {
            value: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            focus() {
                this.$emit('focus');
                this.$parent.$emit('focus');
            },
        }

    }
```

Let's call this `my-field.vue` component.

```
<div class="field-container" :class="{ focused, filled }">
    <slot />
</div>

export default {
        data(){
            return {
                focused: false,
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.$on('focus', () => {
                this.focused = true
            })
        }
    }
```

and let's call this `final.vue` component.

```
<my-field>
     <my-input v-model="test"/>
</my-field>
```

The thing is in `final.vue`, this is the technique i am following.  Now, I want to move away from using `this.$parent.emit('focus')` in `my-input.vue` component as they are tighly coupled. Any great solution ideas to this problem?

Comment: This question looks suspiciously opinion-based. emitting events doesn't make something tightly coupled, as long as the events make sense abstractly. For example, it makes sense that an input would emit an onChange event or a focus event.

Comment: That being said, if you're writing low level components, you should be aware of the full power of custom events: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Comment: if using $emit multiple times too troublesome, maybe in child components, you can try put data in vuex, so that grandparents will access directly from vuex. IF you want to make it decoupled and be reusable, then pass the vuex key from grand parents to grandchilren so that it can store in vuex with a dynamic key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can avoid tight *coupling* of both the *`components`* in below way:

> Since `my-input` is a *base-component* avoid limiting it to custom `attr` /
>   `prop` / `event` as it also has its own sets of attr / event, let's `bind`
>   them all to make them available for all cases (generic).

**my-input.vue**

```
<input v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
export default {}
```

---

> Let's have this as a *stateless* component & controlled by the parent
>   via `props`, this will help it to more generic.

**my-field.vue**

```
<div class="field-container" :class="{ Focused }">
 <slot/>
</div>

export default {
   props: ["Focused"]
}
```

---

> Let this be the *intelligent* component with `logic` / `state` controlling the two 
>   *dumb*
>   components.

**final.vue**

```
<my-field :Focused="focused">
 <my-input v-model="test" @focus="focused = true" @blur="focused = false"/>
</my-field>

export default {
 data () {
  return {
   test: '',
   focused: false
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here:

1. Emit to parent, then emit again from parent. This is totally valid option and it works. this.$parent.$emit is not good, since it assumes there will be grand parent listening and this will become mess at one point or another.
2. Emit to $root: `this.$root.$emit` Also valid option that is useful when there more than one level of emits, but make sure that you have only one listener, or know to differ between the emits - usually we use this approach at top level components.

**Update**
In your case you can do something like this.

```
<my-field : focused="focused">
    <my-input v-model="test" @focus="onFocus" />
</my-field>

methods() {
    onFocus(){ this.focused = true }
}
```

Also have a look here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4332
But unfortunately, your choices with slots are quite limited.

Comment: Thanks Alex. If you look at my example closely, you will realise that it's not the same as having child, parent and grand-parent. so it's a little bit different. how would you implement this for an example 1?

Comment: Updated my answer